# Wordpress pagination not working past page 1

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Working on this site and it's blog posts here:

http://itsuptous.org/team-pages/

The pagination does not work past page 1. Using this as my query:

```
    $posts = query_posts($query_string.'&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=4&paged='.$paged);
```

And this plugin for my pagination: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/faq/

```
    <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
        wp_paginate();
    } ?>
```

Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in the admin panel  Settings > Reading. Blog pages show at most should show the same as the query posts_per_page (so 4). i'd also do the same for syndication.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel - That solved it! Setting the Reading settings both to 4. Thanks a bunch. Wonder why that disparity caused issues. I thought I could independently set how many posts per page per blog layout. I guess not.